# Can TLS create PKI for you?

Tags: tls, rfc

Suppose A and B want to create TLS secure channel.

But they do not have pre-shared secret, or mutually trust Certificate, How do they do?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), research is step one. A basic search will find many protocols that aren't TLS and  use various authentication methods. To name a few: SSH, IPSec, Kerberos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. First you need to have a solution to how to perform authentication - what will the two sides trust, how they will get the PSK or leaf certificates and/or trusted root certificates installed at the two hosts, and then the TLS part will be more or less obvious. TLS itself will not create a PKI for you.